# Find a verb such that " 'the verb' you this much" is the opposite of "cost you this much"

Tags: word-usage, word-request, verbs

I would like to find a verb such that " 'the verb' you this much" is the opposite of "cost you this much". My intuition is that "give" would be such a choice, but I would like to see if there is a better option.

If an example regarding context is helpful, it would be like:

> "doing this could make you earn 1000, but it also would cost you
>   1000".

Comment: *Doing this will cost you a lot. Doing that will **earn** you a lot.* Or doing something else might ***save*** you a lot (cause you to spend a lot less than you otherwise would, reduce / negate the cost).

Comment: Thanks @FumbleFingers. So "earn" can do it right? Feel free to make it an answer thks

Comment: Yes. In general, you ***earn money*** (by doing paid work), where ***you*** is the "subject" of the verb. But some more abstract nouns - "occupations", for example - can serve as the subject, as ***Busking** earns him enough to pay the rent, **My poetry** doesn't earn me a living, **Plastering** earns £300 a day here*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Thanks a lot that is what I would like to know!

Comment: I don't quite understand the context. Do you mean *Doing this could earn you 1000, but it also would cost you 1000* (i.e. - in practice it's "cost-neutral", neither earning nor costing anything)? Is it intended to be significant that you've used ***could*** for the potential earnings, but ***would*** for the cost?

Comment: @FumbleFingers. Yes, your speculation is correct. But the interpretation of my example is not crucial for my request :)

Answer (score 1):

> Saves you this much.

...means costing you this much less.

> Earns you this much
>
> Nets you this much

...refers to an income of this much typically from employment, but can also refer to an investment.

> Returns you this much

...means earns you this much after making an investment.

> Gives you this much

...means you receive this much, which could be the result of earnings or a gift.

> Provides you this much

... means you receive this much, which could be the result of employment, investment, or a gift.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Sean Hare's excellent suggestions, you can also use:

> Pays you this much.